# Android trouble with crash reports in developer console

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, obfuscation, developer-console

So I'm building my app with proguard which obfuscates the code, and I am uploading my mapping.txt to the deobfuscation files. My crash reports show the class and method names, but they don't show line numbers.

In my build.gradle:

```
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

So then I upload as a deobfuscation file:
`ProjectFolder/app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt`

So my question is:

- Am I uploading the correct file for deobfuscation? There is also seeds.txt, dump.txt, usage.txt in that directory.
- Is it possible to get line numbers in my crash reports through play store when building with proguard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe `mapping.txt` is the right one.

As for viewing line numbers, I added the following to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
# To be able to see line numbers in stack traces

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try next time I release an update. Do you have any idea if those rules will compromise the obfuscation and make it more readable or anything like that?

Comment: If you haven't uploaded a deobfuscation file, you will get something like this: `at your.package.name.YourClassName.onCreate(SourceFile:123)` if the error is being caused in line 123 in your `onCreate` method, for example. Once you upload the deobfuscation file (`mapping.txt`) it should display as if you had received the error through Android Studio's logcat when testing. I hope that makes things clearer. :)